# Using tablet as second screen for viewing

Tags: samsung, tablet, secondary-display

Is there any (free) way to use a (Samsung Galaxy Tab S5e) tablet as a second monitor (with Windows) without an app? But if that's the only way, then that'll do.

Comment: An app doesnt mean you have to pay. Even if would work  I wouldnt expect the mouse to work as well.

Comment: As tablets don't provide HDMI or DisplayPort input ports Windows can not directly recognize the tablet on hardware level. Therefore the only way I see is a driver on Windows that adds a virtual display that is then transmitted to a receiver like an Android app. Thus the critical point is not Android but Windows as you would need a special virtual display driver plus attached app. If I search for `windows display driver android app` I get several results, some of them non-free.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am using [spacedesk](https://www.spacedesk.net/#download), but it isn't super smooth enough for watching movies, enough for working and coding. It is available for Android and Apple devices.

You will need to install the same software on Windows. Windows acts as a server. Open the app on your Android, and connect to the same WiFi
(it says even wire can be connected).

Your laptop's software has to be turned on to make it work, but it works well

[image: one windows, two extra monitor]

If you have an Android phone, you can connect that as well. Once everything is set up, don't forget to change the display option in Windows settings.

Hope this serves your purpose.